# How to query Facebook contacts on Android

Tags: android

I have a problem with retrieving facebook contacts. I use simple query:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;    
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, 
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

By this code I obtain all contacts **except** those from facebook.

I have tested contacts by ACCOUNT_TYPE and I found that I receive only contacts from com.sonyericsson.localcontacts and com.google. Any ideas?

Comment: are you using the facebook sdk?

Comment: no, I'm not using facebook SDK. I want to use contact data which are stored(synced) in phone. Do I really need facebook SDK for that?

Comment: well yes, you need to get a list of the users from facebook to test against